# Dynamic comma-separated parameters in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I'm passing a parameter `@list` which contains `'1,2,3,4'` as values to a stored procedure. The `@list` should be converted to `'1','2','3','4'`. Which query do I have to use for that?

Comment: apply split function on @list .Google for split function in sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a solution like this :

```
DECLARE @list VARCHAR(100) = '1,2,3,4'

SET @list = '<N>' + Replace(@list, ',', '</N><N>') + '</N>'
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT c1.value('.', 'varchar(30)') AS List
         FROM   (SELECT Cast(@list AS XML)) t(c)
                CROSS apply c.nodes('/N') AS t1(c1))
SELECT *
FROM   cte
--join abc on cte.List = abc.Column
```

note : if you simply want to put the numbers between single quotes then :

```
DECLARE @list VARCHAR(100) = '1,2,3,4'
SET @list = '''' + REPLACE(@list, ',', ''',''') + ''''
SELECT @list
```